# Cookie set by "Set-Cookie" not detected for another http request

Tags: typescript, http, cookies, setcookie

I have a login process where after a user successfully logs in, a cookie will be set via `"Set-Cookie"` in the response. I've set up my backend with an authentication middleware that always checks for the cookie whenever a new http request is received. So far, when a user logs in from the client, the cookie is successfully stored. However, when I make another request on the client, I somehow lose the cookie; and the server treats the new request as an unauthorized request.

Response header after logging in:
[image: loginResponseHeader]

Request header after sending a request after login:
[image: newRequestRequestHeader]

Codes:
Login - Set-Cookie (server)

```
    public logIn = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const logInData: LogInDto = req.body;
        const user: UserInterface = await this.User.findOne({ email: logInData.email });
        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            const passwordMatch: boolean = await this.authService.matchPassword(logInData, user);
            console.log(passwordMatch);
            if (passwordMatch) {
                const token: Token = this.authService.createToken(user);
                const cookie: any = this.authService.createCookie(token);
                res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [cookie]);
                res.status(200).json(
                    {
                        message: "Login success",
                        user: user
                    }
                );
            } else {
                next(new CredentialsException());
            }
        } else {
            next(new CredentialsException());
        }
    }
```

New Request after login (Client)

```
const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {

    const handleClick = async () => {
        const res: any = await axios.get<any>(
            "http://localhost:4000/getusers",
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
        console.log(res);
    }
```

Authentication middleware (server)

```
export async function authMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    const cookies: any = req.cookies;
    if (cookies && cookies.Authorization) {
        const pubKey: string | Buffer = fs.readFileSync("./server.public.key", "utf8");
        try {
            let verifyOptions: any = {
                algorithm: ["RS256"]
            };
            const tokenPayload: TokenPayload = jwt.verify(cookies.Authorization, pubKey, verifyOptions) as unknown as TokenPayload;
            const _id: string = tokenPayload._id;
            const user: UserInterface | null = await User.findById(_id);
            if (user) {
                req.user = user;
                next();
            } else {
                next(new AuthTokenException())
            }
        } catch (error) {
            next(new AuthTokenException());
        }
    } else {
        next(new AuthTokenException());
    }
}
```

Login from client (first request)

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (loginData: LoginData, thunkAPI: any) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = loginData;
            //config, data, headers, request, status, statusText
            //{ data: resData, headers: resHeaders } 
            const { data: resData, headers: resHeaders } = await axios.post<LoginResponse>(
                "http://localhost:4000/login",
                {
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                },
            );
            console.log(resData);
            console.log(resHeaders);
            return resData;
        }
        catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error.message);
            console.log(thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message));
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
        }
    }
)
```

Are there some headers I need to set when I send the new request in `handleClick`?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the first HTTP request?

Comment: Looks like you just forgot `withCredentials: true` on the first request.

Comment: Did you make the request from a different domain at the frontend / backend ?

Comment: @Quentin I see, why is ```withCredentials``` necessary? (trying to learn)

@ShueiYang Yes they are on different domains, or rather ports (frontend: localhost:3000, backend: localhost:4000

Comment: @code_learner93 show me your cors setting

Comment: Because cookies are credentials and credentials are, by default, ignored for cross origin requests.

Comment: @ShueiYang I have not done any CORS setting, the only thing I did was ```app.use(cors());``` on the backend. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending credential, you will need to specify your url and enable the credential, you cannot use "*"

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // or your exact frontend URL
    methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD",
    credentials: true,  // this is for cookie
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

You don't have to enable credential on your first request since you only try to login, and you re not sending any cookie for the first time. You can check their documentation for more detail https://github.com/expressjs/cors